# Not able to run Spark job on YARN cluster

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, java-8

I have a simple hadoop cluster on top of which Spark runs (that is Spark uses YARN as cluster manager).

I am using Hadoop 2.7; scala 2.112.1; spark 2.1.0 and jdk 8.

Now, when I submit a job, it fails, with the message below:

```
17/04/06 23:57:55 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1491534363989_0004 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/04/06 23:57:56 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1491534363989_0004 (state: FAILED)
17/04/06 23:57:56 INFO yarn.Client:
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: Application application_1491534363989_0004 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1491534363989_0004_000002 exited with  exitCode: 15
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://rm100.hadoop.cluster:8088/cluster/app/application_1491534363989_0004Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1491534363989_0004_02_000001
Exit code: 15
```

Are there any issues with JDK 8?

## **Update**

When I run the same program using JDK 7, it is working fine. So my question is: Is Spark, scala , hadoop having any issues with JDK 8?

Comment: No, we run earlier versions of Hadoop and Spark on JDK 8. It works fine.

Comment: Might be that you ran into some issues with Scala 2.11 as it's Java 8 support is experimental - http://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.11.1#required-java-version

Comment: I believe the problem is with Hadoop, from their Java support page, version 2.7 and above are supported for JDK 7 only.

Comment: According to Hortonworks they thoroughly tested Hadoop with different Java versions and they did not have issues - https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/27327/about-java-8-support.html It'd be useful to see the specific error you get.

Comment: I am using plain Hadoop, not any distribution. Chances are, Hortonworks and cloudera are ahead of plain Hadoop, but I am sharing what I am encountering in my environment; using plain distributions.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using spark over yarn cluster using java 8 and everything runs smoothly. From what I know newer version of spark and scala needs java 8 or above. Here are the few things you need to consider.

1. check for JAVA_HOME path in hadoop-env.sh
2. when you start yarn cluster make sure all the required nodes are up using `jps`.
3. check for logs in hadoop logs.
4. go to `http://rm100.hadoop.cluster:8088/cluster/app/application_1491534363989_0004` for more details

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply; all daemons are running. I tested hadoop2.8 as well, but encountering same issue. Same programs runs on Jdk7, but not on jdk8. Do we need to to any changes in Java settings?

Comment: did you check the application log that comes in the failure message?